# I have three xsd and I wants to access complex type from xsd 3 to xsd 1

Tags: xsd

There are three XSDs XSD A, XSD B and XSD C. XSD A is referring XSD B. And XSD B is referring XSD C. There is some complex types in XSD C which I wants to access in XSD A without importing XSD C. I have tried it but no luck. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without importing the XSD C into A it is not possible to access the complex types directly. what you can do is create additional complex types in XSD B that expose the complex types from XSD C.

example:

XSD C

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/C" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/C" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="C"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Complex_Type_C_1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="C1" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Complex_Type_C_2">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="C2" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Complex_Type_C_3">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="C3" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XSD B

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/B" xmlns:C="http://tempuri.org/C" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/B" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/C" schemaLocation="C.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="B" type="C:Complex_Type_C_1"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Complex_type_B_1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="B1" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Complex_type_B_From_C">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="C:Complex_Type_C_2"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XSD A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/A" xmlns:B="http://tempuri.org/B" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/A" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/B" schemaLocation="B.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="A">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Types">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Btype" type="B:Complex_type_B_1"/>
                            <xs:element name="Ctype" type="B:Complex_type_B_From_C"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have also achieved this by extension.